# How to edit existing SharePoint 2013 snippets?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, design-manager

In SharePoint 2013, I use design manager snippets to add code to the page layout after customizing the options. But then later if I want to modify the options, I have to go to design manager and recreate the snippet with the new options and replace the code with the new one. Is there a way I can just reload the existing snippet and then modify it (so that I get back all my configurations)?

Thanks